# Making a table in python with exact spacing

Tags: python, formatting

I am already sitting here, several hours, trying to figure out how to properly do this as a complete Python newbie.
I basically want to create a receipt for shopping bakery products.
However, I just cant get the spacing for it done.
My biggest problem currently is, that I cannot do 2 f-string modifiers at once.
It basically is working with `:>15s`for example, then I cant use `:.2f`in my f-string anymore in order to display 2 decimals.

```
Artikel                 Stk.-Preis       Anzahl      Preis/Euro
------------------------------------------------------------------
Brezen                        0.75           54            40.50
Semmeln                       0.50          344            172.00
Baguettes                     2.10           43           90.30
Dinkel-Vollkornbrot           4.75            2           9.50
```

Here you can already see the problem in the last column, if i do it without `:>(number)s`. It just gets all over the place as soon as it moves from x.xx to xx.xx or even xxx.xx prices.

I tried to do it with `print(f"Semmeln {padding:>21s} {semmel_preis:.2f} {str(semmeln):>12s} {padding:>10s} {semmeln_gesamt:.2f}")`, where "padding" is simply `""`, trying to format it.

Is there an easy way to use for exmaple `semmel_preis:.2f:.>21s`?
If no, how can formatting like this be done easily so that it lines up, no matter how long the numbers are?

My code is looking like this for the table:

```
print("\nArtikel \t\tStk.-Preis       Anzahl      Preis/Euro")
print("------------------------------------------------------------------")
if(brezen>0):
   print(f"Brezen {padding:>22s} {breze_preis:.2f} {str(brezen):>12s} {padding:>10s} {brezen_gesamt:.2f}")
if(semmeln>0):
    print(f"Semmeln {padding:>21s} {semmel_preis:.2f} {str(semmeln):>12s} {padding:>10s} {semmeln_gesamt:.2f}") 
if(baguettes>0):
    print(f"Baguettes {padding:>19s} {baguette_preis:.2f} {str(baguettes):>12s} {padding:>9s} {baguettes_gesamt:.2f}") 
if(dinkel_vollkorn>0):
    print(f"Dinkel-Vollkornbrot {padding:>9s} {dinkel_vollkorn_preis:.2f} {str(dinkel_vollkorn):>12s} {padding:>9s} {dinkel_vollkorn_gesamt:.2f}")
```

Comment: What format is your input data in?

Comment: My data is input as int